# How to derive formula for calculating weights in linear combinations?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, orthogonality

Weights in the linear combination:

If $\{u_{1}, u_{2}, ... , u_{p}\}$ be an orthogonal basis for a subspace $W$ of $R^{n}$
, then for each $y$ in $W$, the weights for the linear combination $y = c_{1}.u_{1} + ⋯ + c_{p}.u_{p}$ can be defined as
$$c_{j} = \frac{y.u_{j}}{u_{j}.u_{j}}  \qquad j=1,2, ... ,p$$

I understood the geometrical interpretation of the above formula, but I want to know how to derive the above equation.

Comment: You can derive that formula using “Fourier’s trick” : starting from the formula for $y$,  take the dot product of both sides with $u_j$, and observe the wonderful simplification that occurs.

Comment: That was quite simple, @littleO . Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y\in W$ and $\{u_{1}, u_{2}, ... , u_{p}\}$ form a basis for $W$, it is possible to write $y$ as a linear combination of $u_{1}, u_{2}, ... , u_{p}$:
$$
y = c_{1}u_{1} + ⋯ + c_{p}u_{p} = \sum_{i=1}^{p}c_{i}u_{p}
$$
Take dot product on both sides with respect to $u_j$:
$$
\begin{align}
y\cdot u_j &= \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{p}c_{i}u_{p}\right] \cdot u_{j}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{p}c_{i}u_{i}\cdot u_{j}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\{u_{1}, u_{2}, ... , u_{p}\}$ are also orthogonal, $u_{i}\cdot u_{j} = 0$ when $i\neq j$ and
$$
y\cdot u_j = c_{j}u_{j}\cdot u_{j}\\
\Rightarrow c_{j} = \dfrac{y\cdot u_j}{u_{j}\cdot u_{j}}
$$